# How can I select the sum of different values of the same type?

Tags: mysql

I'm playing around with the world database in MySQL and I want to list out the sum of each continent's population. I can do this by typing out a very long subquery stating that it should get the sum(population) WHERE continent = "XXXX" and sum(population) WHERE CONTINENT = "YYYY", but it seems very inefficient. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT continent, SUM(population) 
FROM <tablename>
GROUP BY continent
```